# use mysqlimport with compressed file

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

Is it possible to use mysqlimport (or something of similar performance) in combination with a gzipped tsv file, for example using input redirection?

I don't want to fully unzip the file first because of space limitations.

As far as I understand, mysqlimport only accepts files as input AND uses the filename to determine the table name.

Comment: how limited is space that you cant decompress it?